# Windows 7, every keyboard will only open calculators

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

This is a very strange problem. Yesterday morning after having no issues last night, I powered on my computer and couldn't log in. I eventually realized the problem was my keyboard not typing. I tried 3 different keyboards and got no results, same thing everytime. I eventually logged in using onscreen keyboard.

When I got to the actual desktop I found a horrible issue. Every number and letter key opens a calculator and does nothing else. Hundreds of calculators.

I ran a virus check and found nothing. I uninstalled recent programs. I checked the calculator and made sure there was no shortcut key. I even tried to uninstall the calculator. I tried to restore my system but it failed, I can probably get it to work.

Any advice? I can't seem to find anyone else with this problem.

Comment: So onscreen keyboard works but all 3 physical keyboards launch calculators?

Comment: How about Safe Mode?

Comment: This sounds a little like a prank or some serious misconfiguration. Safe mode, or trying it on a new account sounds like a good idea. On the off chance, how's the keyboard connected?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I kinda agree. Ctrl+Alt+Delete I don't believe is overridable no matter what you do.

Comment: note also that, for the ps/2 keyboard plug interface, one must *sometimes* reboot the computer before it will be recognized. http://superuser.com/questions/172420/is-it-safe-to-hot-swap-a-ps-2-keyboard

Comment: @Bob Yes that is correct.

Comment: @Ramhound I have not tried safe mode yet, I will see if that fixxes the issue.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I have tried two USB connected keyboards and one wireless keyboard. I tried it on one other account and got the same issue. I don't think anyone has had access to this pc to pull a prank.

Comment: I would also add that Symblols like windows key and F1 through F12 do not activate calculators. The spacebar and all the symbols work. It is really only the letters and numbers that open them.

Comment: Problem persists in safemode